# Rain proofing a drone design - What about the motors?

Tags: brushless-motors, waterproofing

I'm working with custom build autonomous drones. Recently, I've started thinking about making the design rain proof.

There are a lot of waterproof RTF designs out there and SO also has a thread on that topic [here](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/570/how-do-you-waterproof-your-electronics). However all of them only deal with electronics and don't mention the most exposed parts - the motors. The waterproof designs I could find don't seem to pay any attention to the motors at all.

On the aforementioned SO thread, the user strepto said that motors are intrinsically waterproof and need no further work. I admit there aren't any open electronics in a motor, it consists of some magnets on the outer hull and isolated copper wire on the inner stator.

However, is this really true in practice? Can a motor really suffer rain without consequences? If no, what are the things I would look out for when choosing a motor? Or would it be better to choose a pusher design with downward facing motors that aren't exposed to rain at all?

Comment: I think it really depends strongly on the exact motor make/model chosen. Some motors are even intended to be water-cooled, but others might have their fluid bearings leak oil (and therefore degrade) in the presence of water. I think the general idea is that almost all BLDC motors are *tolerant* of water intrusion, but hiding the motor body may be a decent idea. (assuming the motor design doesn't rely on air cooling)

Comment: @ifconfig I've never seen a BLDC drone motor without openings at the top and, considering the huge amounts of current it has to withstand, they probably shouldn't be covered completely. So you'd either have to build a motor housing that closes around the motor shaft while still getting air to the motor's vents or, as mentioned, create a pusher design?

Comment: Oh, no :) I meant that there are BLDC motors *in general* that are exclusively water-cooled.